# How do I create a document term matrix from my pandas nested lists?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, lda

I am trying to implement a piece of code using GuidedLDA but I do not understand format my text data needs to be in for it to work. The tutorial code uploads a dataset from the module itself whereas I have extracted my text data from my pandas dataframe, created the corpus and dictionary using gensim and am still unable to make it functional.

Could you help explain how I can structure my text data into a sparse array dataset used in LDA models (document term matrix I think?) so I can utilised the GuidedLDA module?

I originally followed this tutorial to run LDA analysis on text data:
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/

After wanting to improve it, I wanted to use seed topics to tailor it. So I found this tutorial:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-we-changed-unsupervised-lda-to-semi-supervised-guidedlda-e36a95f3a164

But the GuidedLDA has been giving me so many errors because I can't match the structure of the dataset used in it.

I have tried:
 - changing my corpus into an array to get the shape

- Made X = corpus
- Structure my corpus as a BoW model
- Used DictVectorized

This is tutorial code found here https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-we-changed-unsupervised-lda-to-semi-supervised-guidedlda-e36a95f3a164:

```
X = guidedlda.datasets.load_data(guidedlda.datasets.NYT)
vocab = guidedlda.datasets.load_vocab(guidedlda.datasets.NYT)
word2id = dict((v, idx) for idx, v in enumerate(vocab))
print(X.shape)
print(X.sum())

model = guidedlda.GuidedLDA(n_topics=5, n_iter=100, random_state=7, 
refresh=20)
model.fit(X)

topic_word = model.topic_word_
n_top_words = 8
for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
    topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-
```

(n_top_words+1):-1]
        print('Topic {}: {}'.format(i, ' '.join(topic_words)))

My code:

```
# Create Dictionary 
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(processed_sums_bigrams)

# Create Corpus (list of documents)
texts = processed_sums_bigrams

# Term Document Frequency
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

X = corpus
vocab = id2word
print(X.shape)
print(X.sum())
```

When X = corpus or id2word:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

When X = np.array(corpus[0]):

X.shape >>> (36,7)

This shape is too small. 
The tutorial code shape is (8447, 3012) and sum is 1221626.

Then I receive this error:

--> 47     print('Topic {}: {}'.format(str(i), ' '.join(topic_words)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int32 found

I have also encountered other errors in my attempts to turn my corpus of text data into some kind of sparse array that resembles the document term matrix used in the tutorial code including:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'